# jQuery list items and menus method/function

Tags: javascript, jquery, algorithm, function, methods

I want to clean up my code a bit.. mechanism/algorithm like suggested in my question in another post.

[list item stay open on click a link or reload/refresh page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68784354/list-item-stay-open-on-click-a-link-or-reload-refresh-page/68805339#68805339)

I do not want to repeat myself over and over again. If I add more list items and menus to the code. Maybe someone can help me with a function/method to write less code.

Here is my html:

```
        <ul>
          <li class="menu"><a href="#">Server</a></li>
            <ul>
              <li class="item">
                <span>
                  <a href="#1">Start</a>
                </span>
              </li>
              <li class="item">
                <span>
                  <a href="#2">Security</a>
                </span>
              </li>
            </ul>
        
          <li class="menu"><a href="#">GIT</a></li>
            <ul>
              <li class="item">
                <span>
                  <a href="#1">blub</a>
                </span>
              </li>
              <li class="item">
                <span>
                  <a href="#2">wurst</a>
                </span>
              </li>
            </ul>
        </ul>
```

And my jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   
    $(".item").hide();

    $(".menu").click(function() {
        
        localStorage.setItem('clickedItem', '.menu');

        $(".item").hide();

        $(this, ".item").show();

    });    
});
```

Here is a JSFiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/ngy5mb4q/2/

I am a bit new to functions/methods, thats why I need a bit help. Maybe someone can show me an example, so that I can understand it better.

Answer (score 0):

First of all I would like to point out that this is not the correct way to create nested lists. See this [proper-way-to-make-html-nested-list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5899337/proper-way-to-make-html-nested-list)

Now, you can define a jQuery function say `createList(arr)` to create a list for you dynamically. The parameter `arr` is passed to the function which contains the text to be shown in the list i.e.,

```
arr = ["Server", "Start", "Security"]
```

where `arr[0]` can represent the list title and the rest are `<li>` elements of the sub-list. You can call this function at the start of your webpage loading to create the listts.

Something like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  arr = ["Server", "Start", "Security"];
  arr1 = ["GIT", "blub", "wurst"];

  function createList(arr) {
    var n = arr.length;
    $("#masterList").append('<li class="menu"><a href="#">' + arr[0] + '</a></li>');
    if (n > 1) {
      var i = 1;
      var li = $("#masterList").append('<li style="list-style:none"></li>').children('li:last-child');
      var ul = li.append('<ul></ul>').children('ul:last-child');
      while (i < n) {
        ul.append('<li class="item"><span><a href="#1">' + arr[i] + '</a></span></li>');
        i++;
      }
    }
  }
  createList(arr);
  createList(arr1);

  $(".item").hide();

  $(".menu").click(function() {

    //localStorage.setItem('clickedItem', '.menu');

    $(".item").hide();

    $(".item").show();

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="masterList">
</ul>
```

If you want to create sub-sub-lists then you might want to think something better that this or you can still use this but might want to try some better way of passing the `arr` to indicate which element belongs to which level and use recursion along with it. Just an idea, pass another array named `depth` which has the depth mentioned of every item in the `arr` array. Thus add it appropriately in the DOM using jQuery. The simpler version is shown above.